# Are the questions getting easier and less complex?

Tags: discussion

Why are the questions on Biology SE so easy? Did something happen to scare off the more complex questions? They do not look like they have much research invested into them.

Comment: i guess the more troublesome issue is that the easy or i would say popular questions and their answers get more votes than a question/answer with really a great amount of effort. We don't know how to appreciate effort. That makes me think- should right to vote require higher reputation points. *This is a new question in itself. I also think like this about our democracy and politics :P*

Comment: Maybe because not all of us are proffesional biologists - rather just curious people. By the way, I didn't get much complex answers on my easy questions. I wouldn't get any on complex questions I guess.

Answer (score 3):

I think this varies - as it also does with the number of questions per day. And depending on your profession (lets say biologist or biochemist) a lot of these questions seem easy or even trivial. Nevertheless they deserve to be answered in a proper way.